# Doctrine DQL Order By Name Field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I am using dql to query my table.

```
 $dql   = "SELECT p FROM WIC\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing p order by p.name";
```

I have two tables, `Listing` and `Products`.

In the `Listing` Table I have `product_id` field which references the `Products` Table `id` field.

I want to be able to order my query by the `Product` Table `name` field but I also want to keep getting an error each time I do `p.name`. `p.name` does NOT exist in the `Listing` Table, thats why it is throwing the error, I just don't know how to do it properly.

`Listing` entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\ProductBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="listings", cascade={"remove","persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Common\Versioned
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $product;
```

Comment: is "name" mapped in the model?

Comment: what is the definition for `name` in `WIC\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing` entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LEFT JOIN

Try this way:

```
 $dql   = "SELECT l FROM WIC\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing l LEFT JOIN l.product p order by p.name";
```

Comment: I am getting this error: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 70 near 'p order by p': Error: Class WIC\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing has no association named Products ... I have edited my entity in the original post